# Using State Machine for Controlling Data

Tags: state-machine, atmega

I am sending some data from one Atmega644P to another Atmega644P consecutively. The first three bytes are SYN(0x16), DLE(0x10), and STX(0x02). On the receiving part, I made a state machine to control if I receive those bytes correctly.

When it is in DLE_1_s state, it goes directly to the "else" statement, although the data is 0x10. Why is this happening?

I am using Peter Fleury's uart library.

This is the diagram I am trying to implement:
[image]

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 0b11111010;  //  PORTD input/output.
    DDRC = 0xFF;

    uart_init( UART_BAUD_SELECT(UART_BAUD_RATE,F_CPU) );

    sei();

    unsigned int rec_char;
    char buffer[7];

    while(1)
    {
        rec_char=uart_getc();

        switch(state)
        {
            case SYN_s:
                {                   
                    if ((unsigned char) rec_char == 0x16) // SYN
                    {
                        state=DLE_1_s;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state=SYN_s;
                    }
                }
            break;

            case DLE_1_s:
                {
                    if ((unsigned char) rec_char == 0x10) // DLE
                    {
                        state=STX_s;
                    }
                    else if ((unsigned char) rec_char == 0x16) // SYN
                    {
                        state=DLE_1_s;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state=SYN_s;
                    }
                }
            break;

            case STX_s:
                {
                    if ((unsigned char) rec_char == 0x02) // STX
                    {
                        state=TARGET_NO_1_s;
                    }
                    else if ((unsigned char) rec_char == 0x16) // SYN
                    {
                        state=DLE_1_s;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state=SYN_s;
                    }
                }
            break;
```

Comment: in the `case DLE_1_s:` case, if the character is not 0x10 but 0x16 you should not fall back to the `SYN_s` state, but stay in the `DLE_1_s` state instead. (and maybe emit a 0x10 character, I don't know the particular protocol)

Comment: @wildplasser : Structure of a data telegram is here: [Telegram](http://oi59.tinypic.com/1zx8qhf.jpg)

I thought I needed to check the first three bytes to see if I'm synchronized correctly. If I receive one of those three bytes wrong, I should go back to the beginning and wait for the new data. That's what I thought.

Comment: You expect `SYN,DLE,STX` What should the FSM do when it encounters `SYN,SYN,DLE,STX` ? That was what I said in my first comment.

Comment: According to [Peter Fleury's documentation](http://homepage.hispeed.ch/peterfleury/group__pfleury__uart.html#ga1), `uart_getc` returns an unsigned int.  But you are assigning it to a char.  That may be a problem.

Comment: @wildplasser Okay, I see your point. But if I stay in the same state, what happens if FSM encounters 'DLE' and 'STX' in the following data frame?

Comment: The casting would not be necessary if uart_getc() would return an int just like getc(). (EOF is probably handled differntly anyway) For an 8-bit return value both signed and unsigned returns could be used.

Comment: Just draw the state-diagram before implementing it. Decide what you should do on fallback (probably just emit the consumed characters)

Comment: @wildplasser I've editted my question and added the diagram and new code. But still have the same problem.

Comment: Pleas add a start state (state#0) to your diagram.

Comment: You say that, "it goes directly to the "else" statement, although the data is 0x10".  How do you know that the data is 0x10?  Have you stepped through this in a debugger?  Are you sure that uart_getc() even returned a character?  You should check the status in the high byte of rec_char after calling uart_getc().

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FAKE 1
#if FAKE
unsigned DDRD, DDRC;
#define  UART_BAUD_RATE 123
#define  F_CPU 0
#define UART_BAUD_SELECT(a,b) (((a)<<8)+((b)&0xff))
#define UART_NO_DATA 1

#define SYN 0x16
#define DLE 0x10
#define STX 0x02

extern void uart_init(unsigned);
extern void sei(void);
extern void maybe_sleep(void);
extern unsigned uart_getc(void);
#endif

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = 0b11111010;  //  PORTD input/output.
    DDRC = 0xFF;

    uart_init( UART_BAUD_SELECT(UART_BAUD_RATE,F_CPU) );

    sei();

    unsigned int rec_char;
    int state;

    for(state=0; ; ) {
        unsigned int hi,lo;

        rec_char = uart_getc();
        hi = rec_char >> 8;
        lo = rec_char & 0xff;

        switch (hi) { /** handle errors from uart here */
        case 0: break;
        case UART_NO_DATA: /* no receive data available */
                maybe_sleep();
                continue;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Hi=%x Lo=%x\n", hi, lo);
            /* some cleanup here ... */
            state =0;
            continue;
            }

        switch(state) {
        case 0:
            if (lo == SYN) { state = 1 ; break;}
            break;
        case 1:
            if (lo == DLE) { state = 2; break; }
            if (lo == SYN) { break; }
            state= 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            if (lo == STX) { state = 3; break; }
            if (lo == SYN ) { state = 1; break; }
            state = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
           /* handle payload here ... */
           break;
           }
    }
    return 0;
}
```